# Как добавить подтверждение email без использования identity?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, email

Как добавить подтверждение email без использования identity?

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Register(Registration account) {
    if (ModelState.IsValid) {
        var user = db.Registration.FirstOrDefault(p = >p.Email.Equals(account.Email));
        if (user != null) {
            ModelState.AddModelError("Email", "Данная почта уже занята");
        }
        else {
            db.Registration.Add(account);
            db.SaveChanges();
            ModelState.Clear();
            ViewBag.Message = account.Email + " " + "Вы удачно зарегистрировались";
        }
    }
    return View();
}
```

Мне нужно сделать сброс пароля и чтобы при регистрации отправлялся подтверждающий mail... но не могу понять как надо сделать,ведь я не использую identity a во всех сайтах примеры с identity ..я при логине использую сессии. http://metanit.com/sharp/mvc5/12.8.php

Answer (score 1):

Добрый день. Можно добавить дополнительное bool поле в `Account`, которые будет информировать о том, подтвердил ли свой EMail пользователь или нет. После этого создадим ещё одну таблицу, модель, например, `EMailValidate`. В нём нам нужно будет добавлять код для активации EMail'a и параметр, который мы будем использовать для подтверждения. Например: `Username`, `Code`, `Status`. Создаём метод отправки EMail'a пользователю и добавления записи в новую таблицу. Создаём метод, на который попадает юзер при переходе по ссылке. Внутри метода делаем запрос к БД, проверяем такой код. Если находим, то меняем в этой таблице `Status = true`, чтобы нельзя было активировать ещё раз, берём `Username`, находим в `Account` и ставим `Status = true`. Желательно ещё удалять запись из `EMailValidate` после активации. Если будете удалять, поле `Status` в ней не нужно.
Вам необходимо подумать над генерацией кода подтверждения.

Identity позволяет это сделать всё в пару кликов, что упрощает работу. Алгоритмов работы такой системы очень много, я лишь привёл один из множества.